# Загрузка страницы через AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Доброго времени суток.

У меня имеется почти рабочая система, как она работает:

1. Есть JS код который реагирует на нажатия ссылок и анализирует их, имеется ли у них атрибут **"sc-hapi"** или нет, если есть, то выполнять ajax запрос, если нет, то переходить по ссылке как обычно.
   **script.js**

   ```html
   <script>
       $("[sc-hapi]").click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var href = $(this).attr('href');
           ContentLoad(href, true);
       });

       function ContentLoad(url) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php?mode=ajax&do=load_page&page=' + url,
               method: 'post',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {},
               success: function(data) {
                   NProgress.start();
                   console.log(data)
                   history.pushState(null, null, url);
                   NProgress.done();
                   $("#content").html(data._page);
               }
           });
       }
   </script>
   ```
2. Если имеется атрибут, то выполняем запрос AJAX где получаем предполагаемую ссылку и передаем ее обратно в виде json, после чего, дальнейший код JS из первого пункта загружает нужную нам страницу.
   **load_page.php**

   ```html
   <?php
   if (!defined("SC")) {
       exit("Попытка взлома!");
   }

   class submodule
   {
       private $core;
       public function __construct($core)
       {
           $this->core        = $core;
       }


       public function content()
       {
           $page = ((isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : "test");
           switch ($page) {
               case '/login':
                   $content = "/login/index";
                   break;
               case '/rules':
                   $content = "/rules";
                   break;
               case '/register':
                   $content = "/register/index";
                   break;
               default:
                   $content = "/general";
                   break;
           }
           return $this->core->LoadPageJs($this->core->LoadPage("modules" . $content));
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

**Function LoadPage**

```html
public function LoadPage($path, $data = array())
    {
        ob_start();
        include(Root . '/theme/' . $path . '.phtml');
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

**Function LoadPageJs**

```html
public function LoadPageJs($page)
    {
        $data = array(
            "_page" => $page
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
```

Данный код работает отлично, с одним исключением, если элемент не обновляется (в моем случае navbar где есть ссылки с атрибутом **sc-hapi**), он будет отлично загружать страницы, но если загрузить страницу с такими же атрибутами, то JS не будет их замечать и будет переходить по ссылке как обычно.

Возможно ли как то JS заставить их видеть, например обновить этот самый JS, что бы он начал видеть новые атрибуты?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении данной проблемы.

P.s. Я знаю что есть более легкие способы загрузок страниц, но мне бы хотелось использовать мой код как основу, спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас просто обработчики не вешаются на новые ссылки. Вы их повесили один раз на существующие ссылки, а когда с загрузкой страницы появились новые ссылки ( и удалились старые ), повесить обработчики на них уже забыли.

Повесьте их сразу после загрузки страницы:

```js
function addListeners(selector = "[sc-hapi]") {
    $(selector).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        ContentLoad(href, true);
    });
}

function ContentLoad(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?mode=ajax&do=load_page&page=' + url,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            NProgress.start();
            console.log(data)
            history.pushState(null, null, url);
            NProgress.done();
            $("#content").html(data._page);
            // Подписываемся только на ссылки внутри "#content"
            addListeners("#content [sc-hapi]");
        }
    });
}

addListeners();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это как раз таки то что мне нужно было, спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Возникла проблема, код работает, но он будто выполняется циклически, в логах при переходе по ссылке он загружает страницу от 3 до +10 раз

Comment: Да, такое может быть, если у вас будут ссылки с **sc-hapi** за пределами элемента с `id="content"`. Получается, что обработчик вешается на ссылки несколько раз. Обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь это безупречно работает♥